# -webkit- prefix on animations

Tags: css, animation, webkit, prefix

I saw some CSS where the the `-webkit-` prefix was used both inside `@keyframes` and `@-0webkit-keyframes`.

I'm talking about [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css)

Is that required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-webkit-` prefix is required with both `@keyframes` and `animation*` in these browsers:

```
Chrome  <= 42
Firefox <= 15
Safari  <= 8
Opera   <= 29
Safari&Chrome (iOS) <= 8.4
Android browser <= 4.4.4
```

Lets take for example this code:

```
.animated {
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

This code will work in IE 11 and Firefox 37, but will not work in Chrome 40 and not in Safari 7.

If you will change the code to:

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

This code will work in latest versions of chrome/firefox/safari, but will be ignored in IE 10.

This is why it's advised to have both options:

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

And the same works for `@keyframes` and `@-webkit-keyframes`.

If you care only about new up-to-date versions, you can avoid the `-webkit-` prefix. Otherwise I advise to use both versions.

Comment: I understand that but are -webkit- properties required inside both @keyframes and -webkit-keyframes ? to me it's seems logical that only @-webkit-keyframes would need them, but that css library uses them in both

Comment: Check now. Let me know if the example is good enough to understand.

Comment: Yes I understand but that's not why I asked.. If you take a look at the statement from line 36 of that CSS you`ll see that it contains both `transform` and `-webkit-transform`. I was wondering what's the point of having `transform` if the statement is inside `@-webkit-keyframes`? Shouldn't only `-wekit-transform` be used? Then at line 64 `-webkit-transform` is used within `@keyframes`

Comment: You didn't mention `transform` so I didn't give it in the example, but basically it works the same. If you will use only `transform` - Firefox15 will not know what to do with it. If you will use only `-webkit-transform` - IE11 will not know what to do with it. This is the reason for using both.

Comment: but why would firefox 15 and ie11 read the styles from @-webkit-keyframes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122032/discussion-between-dekel-and-anna-k).